# is there a way to bcp SQL data, pipe it to 7z Compressor and then pipe it AZcopy without dumping to intermediate files?

Tags: windows, powershell, azure, networking, named-pipes

The reason why I want to do this is we have a big table which is well partitioned and wanted to upload to blob storage very quickly by breaking down into multiple pieces using BCP, zipping it using 7z and upload it with AZCopy. Each thread handles each piece but the problem with this approach is it creates multiple intermediate files which in turn creates huge disk queue length & takes a significant amount of time writing to disk. I am looking for a solution which completely bypasses creating those files locally in the disk and directly uploads them. Any idea?

Answer (score -1):

About BCP, until 7zip'ping
May be, through variable.

In Power Shell:
$A = $(bcp << ... actions>>).

$A will be containing result of bcp request.
If 7zip supports API of cmd.exe, piping there. e.t.c.

Comment: No problem, you may use 'bcp' in powershell without any issues. </br> I done it next way: ` bcp "[Versions _Software].[dbo].[Krap_ASDU]" out "d:\Documents and Settings\dskt\exper.csv" -S OAC-NOTEBOOK\SQL -T -c -t "," -r \n `.

Comment: Note, using `bcp' you will keep file in output anyway. If you want to avoid creating files on the disk, use may SQL Import ind Export  data Wizard, why not? or Copy Database Wizard.